# How many rounds are expected?

Tags: probability

You are playing a number of rounds of a game. In every round the game ends with a $p$ chance. In the $N$-th round the game ends anyways. How many game rounds are expected?

The chance of the game ends in exactly the first round is $p$.

The chance of the game ends in exactly two rounds is $(1-p) \times p$.

The chance of the game ends in exactly $k$ rounds is $(1-p)^{k-1}\times p$.

So that's a geometric series and after $r+1$ rounds it seems you have a $$p \times \frac{1-(1-k)^r}{1-(1-p)} = 1-(1-k)^r$$ chance but I do not know how to continue.

Or is it expected value so the expected of the game ending in exactly the $k$ round is $k \times (1-p)^k \times p$ and you need to sum that?

Comment: Weird, I tried using the `$` signs but it didn't work, I thought maybe they changed the markup language since I last posted, thanks for fixing the formatting.

Comment: You are nearly there.  The expectation has the form $E=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} n(1-p)^{n-1}p\right)+N*(1-p)^{N-1}$

Comment: I see... I do not quite understand but I see.